# Can't use "arabtex" package with this template: Option clash for package babel

Tags: arabic, option-clash, arabtex

I am using this [thesis template](https://github.com/mcmanigle/OxThesis). I need to add some arabic text. I need to add this preamble:

```
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
```

Which works for me in a simple article. But with this thesis template, it generates errors:

```
Option clash for package babel.

\begin{alwayssingle} on input line 166 ended by \end{abstract}. \end{abstract}

\begin{abstract} on input line 166 ended by \end{romanpages}. \end{romanpages}

\begin{romanpages} on input line 148 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
```

Can you identify how to make these preamble not conflict with this template?

**EDIT:**

```
This code works in separate tex file.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{علوم الحاسوب}
    \section{تاريخ}
    \begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
        سلام 
    \end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

But the problems arise when I try to incorporate this in this [thesis template](https://github.com/mcmanigle/OxThesis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class file does `\usepackage[greek,latin,english]{babel}` (which in my opinion is not a thing a class should do).

This is such a common problem that the `babel` manual has a note telling you the way out. Page 6 of the manual to v3.40 says

> Some classes load babel with a hardcoded language option. Sometimes,
>   the main language could be overridden with something like that before
>   `\documentclass`:
>
> ```
> \PassOptionsToPackage{main=english}{babel}
> ```

In your case:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=arabic}{babel}
\documentclass{ociamthesis}
```

and remove `\usepackage[arabic]{babel}`.

Comment: Still not working. Do you mean I write `\PassOptionsToPackage{main=arabic}{babel}` before the `\documentclass{ociamthesis}` ?? Also, shall I keep or remove the other packages (see my OP): `arabtex`, `inputenc`, `fontenc`? Please clarify I inserted the `\PassOptionsToPackage{main=english}{babel}` before the `\documentclass` and removed `\usepackage[arabic]{babel}` as you suggested but I got errors.

Comment: I also added an edit.

Comment: @seq yes, before `\documentclass`. your question was only about the option clash error. My solution worked in a MWE I created for myself since you didn't provide one. If you have different errors now, please open a new question and **please [include a MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/), then**

Comment: did you use the template I pointed for your MWE?

Comment: @seq yes, of course I did.